# How to fix unhandled promise rejection warning, cast to objectid failed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose, I am trying to set up a get route to '/featured' in my api but am getting the following error '(node:8989) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" at path "_id" for model "Blog"'

I am fairly sure I'm just doing something wrong when setting up my router for my blogs. I've tried using .find({'featured': true}), tried .find({featured: true}), tried .find().where('featured', true), tried .find().where('featured').equals(true) and all of them result in the same UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError

here is my blog schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    article: { type: String, required: true },
    published: { type: Date, required: true },
    featured: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

here is the route I am having trouble with in blogs.js

```
router.get('/featured', (req, res) => 
{
    Blog
        .find({'featured': true})
        .then(blogs => 
        {
            if(blogs){
                res.status(200).json(blogs)
            }
            else console.log('blogs not found');
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

here is the error stack trace

```
(node:16486) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server is listening on http://localhost:8080
(node:16486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" at path "_id" for model "Blog"
    at new CastError (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:244:11)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:948:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1362:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1352:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1331:15)
    at cast (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:307:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4575:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1783:10)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2038:8)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at process.nextTick (/home/taylour/projects/node200/node200-mongoose-blog-api/node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:16486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

I expect to have the "/featured" route return all blogs where the "featured" boolean value is true, but instead I am getting this error no matter what permutations of the query I try for this route

Comment: Looks like you're trying to query for featured as 'true'. That's a string, not a boolean. Your schema has type boolean. Try it without the quotation marks.

Comment: I've tried that already, it was actually what I tried first, that code snippet was just the copy paste of my most recent try, I'll update it in the snippet though so it looks better and isn't syntactially wrong, edit yeah that wasn't the issue but I did update it so that syntax error won't be an issue. still getting the original error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm new to mongoose, I am trying to set up a get route to '/featured' in my api but am getting the following error '(node:8989) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for **value** "featured" at **path** "_id" for model "Blog"'

This is saying that you have a document *in your mongo collection* that looks like `{_id: "featured"}`. `"featured"` isn't an ObjectId, so mongoose is erroring when it sees that document because it doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: how would I find that item in the collection and remove it? I used the following command to list out all the entries in "blogs" _id parameter and they're all objectId type, none of them just say "featured":  var ids = db.blogs.distinct('_id', {}, {}); printjson(ids);

Comment: Huh! I'm definitely wrong about the `find` being where the error is coming from. In that case, how sure are you that the error is coming from the `find`? It's definitely from somewhere that's trying to do something to a (potential) document with a "path" of _id and a value of "featured".

Comment: I don't really know, that was just my best guess because it's where the error started occurring, when I added that route to the blogs.js router, would it help to post the whole error stack trace? It's not super long

Comment: Yes, that might help!

Comment: I was able to reproduce your exact stack trace by running `Blog.find({_id: "featured" });` I'd look around for code that looks like that (or double-check to make sure that you're running the piece of code that you think you're running). `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" at path "_id" for model "test_coll"`

Comment: Weird, I'll take a look again thanks, if I can find it I'll mark this as closed and give it the checkmark